# How can we do a find/replace on items in a dataframe, based on items in another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list which I convert into a dataframe.

```
labels = ['Airport',
        'Amusement',
        'Bridge',
        'Campus',
        'Casino',
        'Commercial',
        'Concert',
        'Convention',
        'Education',
        'Entertainment',
        'Government',
        'Hospital',
        'Hotel',
        'Library',  
        'Mall',
        'Manufacturing',
        'Museum',
        'Residential',
        'Retail',
        'School',
        'University',  
        'Theater',
        'Tunnel',
        'Warehouse']
labels = pd.DataFrame(labels, columns=['lookup'])
labels
```

I have this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                    'Name':['Dulles_Airport', 'Syracuse_University', 'Reagan_Library', 'AMC Theater', 'Reagan High School']})
```

How can I clean the items in the df, based on matches in labels? My 'labels' is totally clean and my 'df' is very messy. I would like to see the df like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                    'Name':['Airport', 'University', 'Library', 'Theater', 'School']})
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.str.extract` and nan-replacement:

```py
labels = ['Airport', 'Amusement', 'Bridge', 'Campus', 'Casino', 'Commercial', 'Concert', 'Convention', 
    'Education', 'Entertainment', 'Government', 'Hospital', 'Hotel', 'Library', 'Mall', 'Manufacturing',
    'Museum', 'Residential', 'Retail', 'School', 'University', 'Theater', 'Tunnel', 'Warehouse']
        
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 1954],
    'Name': ['Dulles_Airport', 'Syracuse_University', 'Reagan_Library', 'AMC Theater', 'Reagan High School', 'Shake, Rattle and Roll']
})

df['Match'] = df['Name'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(labels)})")
```

The resulting DataFrame will be

```
   Year                    Name       Match
0  2020          Dulles_Airport     Airport
1  2020     Syracuse_University  University
2  2019          Reagan_Library     Library
3  2019             AMC Theater     Theater
4  2019      Reagan High School      School
5  1954  Shake, Rattle and Roll         NaN
```

If you want to keep the non-matching cells, do this:

```py
df['Match'] = df['Name'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(labels)})")
df.loc[df['Match'].isnull(), 'Match'] = df['Name'][df['Match'].isnull()]
```

The resulting DataFrame will be

```
   Year                    Name                   Match
0  2020          Dulles_Airport                 Airport
1  2020     Syracuse_University              University
2  2019          Reagan_Library                 Library
3  2019             AMC Theater                 Theater
4  2019      Reagan High School                  School
5  1954  Shake, Rattle and Roll  Shake, Rattle and Roll
```

If you want to remove the non-matching cells, do this:

```
df['Match'] = df['Name'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(labels)})")
df = df.dropna()
```

The resulting DataFrame will be

```
   Year                 Name       Match
0  2020       Dulles_Airport     Airport
1  2020  Syracuse_University  University
2  2019       Reagan_Library     Library
3  2019          AMC Theater     Theater
4  2019   Reagan High School      School
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most pure `pandas` answer but you could write a function that performs a check for the string against your labels list and apply that to the Name column i.e.

```
def clean_labels(name):

  labels = ['Airport','Amusement','Bridge','Campus',
        'Casino','Commercial','Concert','Convention',
        'Education','Entertainment','Government','Hospital',
        'Hotel','Library','Mall','Manufacturing','Museum',
        'Residential','Retail','School','University',  'Theater',
        'Tunnel','Warehouse']
        
  for item in labels:
    if item in name:
      return item
```

```
>>> df.Name.apply(clean_labels)
0       Airport
1    University
2       Library
3       Theater
4        School
```

I'm assuming here there aren't any typos when comparing the strings and it will return a NoneType for anything that doesn't match.